# Ms Access - How to verify the date time format displayed in yyyy/mm/dd HH/MM/SS

Tags: sql, ms-access

May I know could I verify whether the date displayed in the field is in specific format

As per my requirement, the datetime should be displayed in format 'yyyy/mm/dd HH(24hr)/MM/SS'
Eg: The valid value should be '2014/07/18 14:16:48'. If the date is displayed as '18/07/2014 14:16:48', then it is invalid.

Using query how I verify whether it is shown in the format which I have expected. I could use IsDate option to verify it is a valid date and also I could use Mid function to verify the date separator which is '/', but how could I verify the format.

Thanks

Comment: what is the type of your field? datetime? string?

Comment: This could get tricky (unless I am oblivious to another route) because you don't specify what kind of date formats you may receive to validate. There is 1/1/14, 1/1/2014, Jan 1, 2014, 2014/1/1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is stored as `Text`, use the SQL `Like` operator. Select valid dates:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate Like "####/##/## ##:##:##"
```

Select invalid dates

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate Not Like "####/##/## ##:##:##"
```

`#` stands for a single digit.

See [Like Operator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx).

But note that this only makes sense if `myDate` is a `Text`! If the type of `myDate` is `Date/Time`, the date is stored in a numeric format internally and is only formatted as a date for display. So don't confuse the date value per se and the date as it is displayed.

A `Date/Time` is always stored in the same way, no matter how it is formatted and displayed!

Comment: to meet requirement (and assuming text) should use also isDate `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate Like "####/##/## ##:##:##" and isDate(myDate)`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to open the Table in Design View and to set the `Format` property.

[image]

Comment: This does format the date for display, but it does not verify anything.

Comment: A date is a date, whatever format it is in. The format is only for display purposes, and internally stored as number. He has been asking about displaying only in the question. If the input must also be in the same format then the `Input Mask` property can be used in addition to `Format` property.